# Macro coding, how to automate renaming a document to the above folders name

Tags: vba, ms-word, file-rename

I want Word VBA macro to rename the document to the folder it lives in.

```
Sub SaveAsDOCX()
'
OpenDocName = ActiveDocument.FullName
lengthFileName `enter code here`= Len(OpenDocName)
OpenDocName = Left(OpenDocName, lengthFileName - 4)
'
ChangeFileOpenDirectory (ActiveDocument.Path & "\")
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=(OpenDocName & ".docx"), 
FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", 
AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, 
EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, 
SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=0
ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Right now the code functions to rename the DOCX as the old file name, but I want to extract from the directory the folders name, and rename the document that. Unfortunately I need this macro to run in a lot of different folders so I need it to stay dynamic, and can't use explicit folder paths.

Comment: Have you considered using `document.path` or `.fullname` and then edit the resulting string to remove everything before or after the / character?

Comment: Good suggestion. I wasn't aware of the "split" function at the time of posting. It's a lifesaver

Answer (score 1):

'That line gets the Full path to the Folder where the document is located.

```
 ThisDocument.path
```

'That line get the FullPath to the Document place

```
ThisDocument.FullName
```

Example one , you can create a new string for the name document

```
 dim docpath as string
 Dim docname As String
docname = VBA.Split(VBA.Mid(ActiveDocument.FullName, VBA.InStrRev(ActiveDocument.FullName, "\") + 1), ".")(0)
DocPath = ThisDocument.Path & "\" & docname &  ".docx"
```

Example 2

```
dim docpath as string
 Dim docname As String
docname = Vba.Split(ActiveDocument,".")(0)
DocPath = ThisDocument.Path & "\" & docname &  ".docx"
```

I do not know if is that you want , please , comment below if that helped you , i want to help you!

Comment: Ronan, while I modified your code a little bit, your examples got me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: No problem , im here for help you , can you upvote the answer ? Thx

Answer (score 1):

Actually pretty simple. Used the ActiveDocument to get the path string, split it, ubound to the top, -1 to locate the parent folders name in the array, and then called that resulting string. The ending code looks like:

```
Dim name, nameSplit, ParentFolderName
OpenDocName = ActiveDocument.FullName
nameSplit = Split(OpenDocName, "\")
ParentFolderName = (UBound(nameSplit) - 1)
```

and then when performing SaveAs2 call the following as the FileName:=

```
(nameSplit(ParentFolderName) & ".docx")
```